# Total number of possible combinations for a vector of variable length

Tags: statistics, combinations

I am trying to understand the formula behind generalizing the computation of the number of unique combinations possible for a vector of length n. Say x=(a,b,c) with n  = 3, the number of possible combinations would be: [3 choose 1 (a,b,c) + 3 choose 2 (ab, ac, bc) + 3 choose 3 (abc) ]. While if n is 4, the number of possible combinations would be [4 choose 1 (a,b,c,d) + 4 choose 2 (ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd) + 4 choose 3 (abc, abd, bcd, acd) + 4 choose 1 (abcd)], and so on for increasing number of n. But what is the general formuation for these type of combinations?

Thanks for any help! 
Fra

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{}_nC_k = 2^n$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{}_nC_k = 2^n - 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With each of the $n$ components of the vector, you have 2 options - select it or not. So the number of combinations is $2^n$. If you want to exclude the case where none of the components are chosen, then subtract 1.

Comment: Thank you for both the answers and help! I still don't understand how to get the final number from n, for n=3 it should be 7 and for n=4 it should be 11, but do I need to specify each number to choose then (each number from 2 to n for example)? sorry if this seems basic...

Comment: With $n=4$, there are $2^4-1=15$ combinations which are a,b,c,d,ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd,abc,bcd,acd,abd,abcd.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I realized my real experiment is a bit more complicated in that it includes also cases that are positives and negatives, i.e. for n=3 and choose 2, there are two ways of choosing 2 (a negative and a positive); for n=3 and choose 3, there are two ways of choosing 3. Same for n=4: for choose 2, there are two ways of choosing 2; for choose 3, there are two ways etc... But if I try all these combinations it does not add up to 2 x 2^n...